# Server Multiple network connections windows server 2012

Tags: networking, vpn, lan, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using windows server 2012 on my server. I have two connections to be connected to the server.

1. The first is an APN connection to our internal equipment.
2. The second is a LAN connection with internet access.

I need some applications to target the APN connection and any other app uses internet as usual.

is there a feature in windows server which handles this?

Comment: This naturally happens when two different logical network addresses are connected to two different network adapters.  The windows routing table sends the traffic out the appropriate network adapter based on what network you’re trying to reach.

Comment: no it doesn't , i need to disconnect the LAN so that i can ping on an APN IP

Comment: I understand it’s not, that is why you posted your question. But, you asked if there is a “feature” in Windows for this. There is not, because this is always “enabled” through the natural process of route selection. If you have the SAME IP addresses connected to two different network adapters that aren’t the SAME networks then you cannot do that. The devices on the APN network have to have a different set of IPs from the ones you use on the other adapter. And there should be a single default gateway for all “other” traffic configured on the internet adapter.

Comment: If you want further help, you need to [edit] your post and include the IP configuration of each network adapter and give an example IP address of a device you are trying to reach on the APN adapter. Because there isn’t a “feature” that can fix this. This is a function of proper network design.